# Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'html' before initialization

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Can someone explain to me the weird error messages that occur both in chrome and firefox when trying to access a variable before the let declaration: "let X".

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        showJobs();
        function showJobs() {
            let html = '' +
                '@foreach(auth()->user()->jobs as $job)'+
                '<tr>'+
                '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->id }}</td>'+
                '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->employment_type }}</td>'+
                '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->start_date }}</td>'+
                '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->end_date }}</td>'+
                '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->state }}</td>'+
                '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->city }}</td>'+
                '<td>'+
                '<form action="{{ route('job.destroy', $job->id) }}" method="post">'+
                '@csrf'+
                "@method('DELETE')"+
                '<div class="btn-group">'+
                "<a href="+{{ route('job.edit', $job->id) }}+" class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>Delete</a>"+
                '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Edit</button>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</form>'+
                '</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '@endforeach'+
                $('#showJobs').append(html);
        }
    });
</script>
```

I get this error.

[image: error]

I put already these codes

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, the very least you should do is dropping `+` at the end of '@endforeach'. But I'm not sure how exactly you're going to combine the output of server and client here, to be honest.

Comment: I get this error again now, https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FebR.png

Comment: Very strange way to mix php and javascript

Answer (score 1):

**can't access lexical declaration before initialization**

A lexical variable was accessed before it was initialized. This happens within any block statement when let or const declarations are accessed before they are defined.

In your code, html variable was accessed before it was declared `$('#showJobs').append(html);`

**unexpected token: identifier**

This is the syntax error.

In your code, you should write this in single quote instead of double quote `"@method('DELETE')"`

Because double quote already in use while converting

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

Here is correct code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    showJobs();
    function showJobs() {
        let html = '' +
            '@foreach(auth()->user()->jobs as $job)'+
            '<tr>'+
            '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->id }}</td>'+
            '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->employment_type }}</td>'+
            '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->start_date }}</td>'+
            '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->end_date }}</td>'+
            '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->state }}</td>'+
            '<td class="fw-normal">{{ $job->city }}</td>'+
            '<td>'+
            '<form action="{{ route('job.destroy', $job->id) }}" method="post">'+
            '@csrf'+
            '@method('DELETE')'+
            '<div class="btn-group">'+
            "<a href="+{{ route('job.edit', $job->id) }}+" class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>Delete</a>"+
            '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Edit</button>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</form>'+
            '</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '@endforeach';
            $('#showJobs').append(html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth; a suggested answer for when you can also get this error.

I discovered I was getting the same error because I was re-declaring `i` further down in my loop.

After renaming the main loop counter all was well again.